# woocommerce checkout - is it possible to get the functionality of a specific shipping zone for a specific shipping class?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The following code will detect the cart if it has shipping class

i got this here (https://isabelcastillo.com/woocommerce-check-shipping-class)

```
<?php if ( cart_has_product_with_shipping_class('small-items') ): ?>

 Shipping Method 1

<?php elseif ( cart_has_product_with_shipping_class('big-items') ): ?>

 Shipping Method 2

<?php else:?>

 Shipping Method 3

<?php endif;?>
```

i just want to know if i can get the shipping method for a shipping class so that when i choose the "small-items" it will get the functionality of the shipping method 1

Comment: **Reminder:** *Shipping classes allow to have different rates at the product level for a "Flat rate" shipping method*. So you can't get a specific shipping method just for a specific shipping class… In your code "small-items" Shipping class can be from Shipping Method 1 or 2, same thing for "big-items".

Comment: i see..so only the "flat rate" shipping method allows this functionality...:(

Comment: is there any possible solution for me to do this? sorry just a newbie here.

Comment: You should better think what you want to display for each shipping method first as you can't use shipping classes for the display… so think about first. Then add editing your question all details about the Shipping Methods types used for each Zone…